# Finding function from its solutions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let's say I want to find a function of which I only know its solutions, i.e. the points where it goes to zero.

$x_0 \: | \: f(x_0) = 0$ 
$x_1 \: | \: f(x_1) = 0$ 
$...$

Is there a way to programmatically find the function? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Notice that if you have two functions $f$ and $g$ which both have the same roots, then any linear combination
$
a f(x) + b g(x)
$
also has those roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can always find *some* function, but no, you cannot find  **the** function with this property.

Here's why. Suppose we know that there's only one root (it's called a "root", not a "solution"), e.g. $f(0) = 0$. Then
$$
f(x) = x, f(x) = xe^x, f(x) = x^{13}, f(x) = 13x, \ldots
$$
are all different functions with exactly that one root.

But if you want to find just *one*, there's a particularly simple one that's easy to write down: the Lagrange Interpolating polynomial. (It actually solves a more general problem). For this particular problem, that turns out to be
$$
L(x) = (x-x_0) (x - x_1) \cdots (x - x_n)
$$
where  $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ are your roots. If you have infinitely many roots, this may not work, in which case a different solution will do:

$$
H(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x = x0, x1, \ldots...\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$H$ has the disadvantage that there's no pretty algebraic expression, and it's not generally continuous. If you want a *continuous* or *differentiable* function with infinitely many specified roots, you sneak into the realm of analysis, where such questions get addressed one at a time.

For instance, if you say "I'd like a continuous function whose roots are exactly all the rational numbers", the answer is "there's no such function: if $f$ is continuous and zero on the rationals, then it's everywhere zero on the reals."

Comment: Thanks a lot. The L(x) solution you proposed is probably what I was searching for. Actually, shame on me because I didn't think about it before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is called [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

You have to specify the type of the function you want. This gives a functional term with parameters. The mathematical problem is transformed to the problem of calculating the parameters.

There is software available for functions often used in sciences and engineering:
[TableCurve 2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TableCurve_2D)
[TableCurve 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TableCurve_3D)